# android call recording on htc one m8

Tags: android, audio, android-5.0-lollipop, htc-android

I'm writing a call recording component and I am testing it on HTC One M8.
the phone is not rooted, and I am using standrad API to record calls like in this example:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.Default); //Also tried Voice Call

//Tried all combinations of the following 2 lines
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100); //Also tried 48000, 8000, 16000 etc
recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME_GOES_HERE);

recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

I also tried with `AudioRecord` which is setup pretty much the same way, got same results.

Before upgrading to Lollipop I could hear both sides of the call very well. After the upgrade I can hear myself good, but the other side volume is very low.
I know some other apps are recording both sides of the call on HTC One M8 without root, so it is obviously something I'm missing.

**Edit:** please note that this worked before Lollipop and is still working on other devices on Lollipop, so I assume (of course I could easily be wrong) that something else - HTC M8 specific - is missing...

What could be applied so both sides can be heard?

Comment: Actually there is - create a MediaRecorder / AudioRecord with VOICE_CALL/DEFAULT/MIC etc audio sources, set parameters such as encoding, bit rate etc and start recording

Comment: Oren is correct. But Oren also forget to include his code.

Comment: You are right,  could you add setup mediarecorder setup code maybe someone can check what is wrong with it... Without this it is hard to say

Comment: I would also like to note that this worked before Lollipop and is working on another device I have (not HTC) with Lollipop, so maybe something else is missing...

Answer (score 0):

We are on the same boat Oren. My app stopped working too. Fe apps seems to be solved this issue without root but I was not able to do it. I am not sure if HTC has non public API for it

Comment: there are boldbeast,call recorder from skvalex and Total Call Recorder. All do it without root

Comment: I have tried all sorts of combinations with public API but was unable to record

Comment: Me too, but as we know it is possible it is just a matter of digging deep enough...